# Intellij IDEA sbt dependenies

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

Intelij idea in project view under external libraries shows sbt dependencies which doesn't exist anymore for the specific project. I had a dependency in project, then I removed it, refreshed the project dependencies and still see it in project view.
It can't be transitive dependency from another lib, because I checked with `sbt-dependency-graph` plugin that dependecy was not present in output after removing it.

I also can browse classes from that removed dependency.

How to tell Intelij Idea not to show removed dependecies in project view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem I am also phasing with IntelliJ. How I deal with it: I manually go to project properties, select the library and manually remove it.

- Click on the project structure menu.
- Go to libraries.
- Find the one it shouldn't be there. Right click, select delete.
- Give IntelliJ some time to refresh (it can get slow for few minutes).